# How to find serial number of Solaris server?

Tags: solaris, hardware

Is there any command which will be available on Sun Solaris Netra T5220 server, to get the machine's serial number?

Comment: Specify Which series of server are you looking for.

Comment: our solaris server is  5.10

Comment: Which series `T` series, `M` Series  or any other.

Comment: Please use following command `prtdiag -v`

Comment: our server is T series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not -- unless you manually put it into the EEPROM using [sneep](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35557_01/doc.81/e35226/ch3_sneep.htm#IGSTB131):

> Oracle Serial Number in EEPROM (SNEEP) provides a software-accessible
> Chassis Serial Number (CSN) for all Oracle Solaris hardware platforms.
>
> SNEEP uses the system EEPROM for persistent storage of the Chassis
> Serial Number and other important user-defined data such as asset
> information, contract ID, or the serial numbers of attached storage
> devices.
>
> The presence of the software-accessible serial number and other
> service-related information can significantly simplify activities
> related to system service and asset management.
>
> Without SNEEP, only a subset of the Solaris-based hardware platforms
> have a mechanism to maintain a software-accessible serial number.
> Among those platforms, there is a wide variety of mechanisms for this,
> making consistent access to this information difficult.
>
> SNEEP provides one simple and consistent interface to the management
> of this information on all Solaris hosts, domains, and zones. SNEEP
> can also reference and maintain the serial number in the configuration
> files for the Oracle Explorer Data Collector.

...

> If your hardware includes the serial number in its EEPROM, then you can view it with the following command:

```
sneep -t hostname,serial,model
```

> If your hardware does not already store the serial number in EEPROM, then you can use SNEEP to include it.
>
> ### You will need to first obtain the serial number and manually enter it into EEPROM.

(my emphasis)

> On most Sun hardware, the serial number is always located on a physical tag somewhere on the machine. The Sun System Handbook tells exactly where to find it for all Sun machines. The handbook can be accessed at My Oracle Support (click the Knowledge tab and then select Sun System Handbook in the left-hand navigation): https://support.oracle.com

...

> ### WARNING:
>
> The decimal number reported in the SPARC boot banner as the serial number when the machine is powered on is NOT the true serial number - it is the decimal form of the "host id". The host id is ordinarily seen in hexadecimal as the output of the Solaris hostid command.

Answer (score 3):

As Yascan stated, prtdiag works well, if you need to obtain this info from the OS and cant get or dont have sneep then I would try the following

I use this is in my script

```
    # prtdiag -v | awk '/Chassis Serial/{getline; getline; print}'
```

get a different look

```
    # prtdiag -v | awk '/Chassis Serial/{print; getline; print; getline; print}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Login to ALOM and do the following and run the below command.

```
sc> showplatform
SUNW,SPARC-Enterprise-T5120
Chassis Serial Number: BEL00011GA
```

Comment: i have also checked... but it doesnt match with serial number of back door of server

Comment: There is no command which can give you the serial number. you have to check it physically on the server

Answer (score 0):

As noted by Jeff, sneep is a useful tool to track the serial # on older hardware as well as from the OS.  Most of the newer hardware, you can successfully get the serial number via the ILOM or XSCF.

And when in doubt, not only have your property team track it, but also the team in charge of the server maintenance as you'll need it for renewals and opening cases with Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

`cfgadm -alv | grep SN` works on my Solaris installation:

```
# cfgadm -alv | grep SN
sata1/0::dsk/c3t0d0            connected    configured   ok         Mod: WDC WD100EFAX-68LHPN0 FRev: 83.H0A83 SN: 1SH5Y67Z
sata1/1::dsk/c3t1d0            connected    configured   ok         Mod: WDC WD100EFAX-68LHPN0 FRev: 83.H0A83 SN: 1SH6LBAZ
sata1/2::dsk/c3t2d0            connected    configured   ok         Mod: WDC WD100EFAX-68LHPN0 FRev: 83.H0A83 SN: 1SHJKKXZ
sata1/3::dsk/c3t3d0            connected    configured   ok         Mod: WDC WD100EFAX-68LHPN0 FRev: 83.H0A83 SN: 1DGP5ETZ
```